# why i cant json_decode my response from API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, guzzle6

I have tried to get data from this source, which is school detail on my country. but when i get the response, i cannot decode my response and it say `Null`. Idk why, but when i try to copy and paste my response result to hardcode, it can be decoded. why ?

i have tried all possible way to solve this, nothing work.

this is my code :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://jendela.data.kemdikbud.go.id/api/index.php/Csekolah/detailSekolahGET?mst_kode_wilayah=026700');

$response = $res->getBody()->getContents();

$result = json_decode($response); // this return NULL

//But when i going to return the $response, it show the response.

return $response;
```

I expect to access the data or maybe just decode my code, and it will help me a lot.

FYI, I'am using Guzzle 6 and Laravel 5.7 to work with this.

i hope someone can try too access it to and help me.

or maybe if you want to test it you can use Curl Ways :

```
$param = 'index.php/Csekolah/detailSekolahGET?mst_kode_wilayah=026700';
$url='http://jendela.data.kemdikbud.go.id/api/'.$param;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);
return $response;
```

Comment: I tested it,  and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `return $response;`

and try the following code:

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($response);

if($enc == 'UTF-8') {
  $response = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $response);    
} 
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($response,true));
```

Comment: This worked for me, I'd love to understand why we need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) document says:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data
>   is deeper than the recursion limit.

You can use [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) or [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) function to determine the problem.

I can't get the whole response, it's timeout and terminated.

Comment: i have tried json_last_error but it return `4`, i think that Syntax Error. how can i solve this ?

Comment: @BobbyRinaldy try to shorten the response, or increase php time limit.

Comment: @adam sadly i cannot fix that json because of goverment API.

Comment: @shingo could u try to run curl ways ? i have add it to my question

Comment: The response is still terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit

Source: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Some debugging tips:

1. Make sure all the characters fall within `utf8`
2. Specify a depth value(higher than the default)
3. Make use of `json_last_error` see: [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

If debugging tip **1** happens to be the cause of the issue, see if you can limit the return to not include the offending characters.

Comment: could u try to run curl ways ? i have add it to my question